# Dollar signs, function keywords and script blocks in powershell

Tags: function, powershell, dollar-sign

I have this powershell script:

```
function Func1 ($val)
{
  Write-Host "$val is processed by Func1";
}

function Func2($val)
{
  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock `
  ${function:Func1} -ArgumentList "$val is processed by Func2 and";
}

function Func3($val)
{
  $function:Func2.Invoke("$val is processed by Func3 and");
}

Func3 "Value";
```

This works - it outputs **Value is processed by Func3 and is processed by Func2 and is processed by Func1** - but I am confused at two things:

What does the **${function:function-name}** code (i.e. a dollar sign followed by an opening curly brace followed by **function** followed by a colon followed by the name of the function followed by a closing curly brace) in Func2 mean? I can see that it invokes Func1, but I don't really understand why it works.

What does the **$function:function-name.Invoke** code in Func3 mean? I sense that it is using script block functionality, since the Invoke method is called, but it's not clear to me how **$function.function-name** is a script block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`function:` is the PsDrive for the Function provider. All functions are stored on this drive. There are other PsDrives including `variable:` and `env:`. Check out `Get-PsProvider` and `Get-PsDrive` for more.

To access a function from the `function:` drive (get its contents, not call it), use `$function:foo` where foo is the name of the function in which to access.

Curly braces are only required when you are accessing a variable that has special character in its name.

The contents of functions are script blocks, which is why it's being used as the scriptblock parameter for `Invoke-Command`.

Every thing in the `function:` psdrive will be a script block, and scriptblock objects have an `Invoke` method which allows you to execute them.

Comment: I'm still confused by this - "To access a function from the function: drive (get it's contents, not call it), use $function:foo". Does this get the contents of the function, or does it get a script block with the functionality of the function? If it only gets the content, then how can you call Invoke on it, as I do in Func3? Also, it's not clear to me yet what ${function:foo} (i.e. with the brace after the dollar sign) does.

Comment: Ah, OK @andy-arismendi, your edits explain things better to me. Is there a reference for all this, or did you find it out by trial and error? I searched high and low, but I couldn't find any official documentation on this. It doesn't help that it's hard to web search for dollar signs and colons.

Comment: The content IS the script block. `$function:Func2 | gm` shows what you are accessing. Just `PS >$function:Func2` calls the ToString method of the scriptblock so only the text content will be shown.

Comment: Check out the PowerShell language specifications: [2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9706), [3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389)